# String Interpolation inside an SQL Command

Tags: c#, string, string-interpolation

Is there an easier way to use the `name` and `phone` variables inside the below insert SQL Command?

[String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) is a way but I don't know how to implement this.

```
String name = textBox1.Text;
String phone = textBox2.Text;  
     
var query = "insert into Customer_info(Customer_Name,Customer_Phone) " +
            "values('" + name + "','" + phone + "');";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query,con);

try {
    con.Open();
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}

catch (Exception Ex) {
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Instead of using concatenated string or string interpolation to build query string from user input, use parameters instead - see [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you really *should* do is use a parameterised query, so your query would look like this:

```
var query = "insert into Customer_info(Customer_Name,Customer_Phone)" +
"values(@name, @phone);";
```

You'd then use a `SQLCommand` object to pass the parameters to the query:

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", phone);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The reason for this is that it avoids the risk of **SQL Injection** (which is one of the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/images/7/72/OWASP_Top_10-2017_%28en%29.pdf.pdf)). Consider for a moment your current query if the `name` passed in contained some SQL, for example if it contained:

> '; DROP TABLE [Customer_info]; --

This would mean that your constructed SQL (if `phone` was blank) would look like this:

```
insert into Customer_info(Customer_Name,Customer_Phone) values ('';
DROP TABLE [Customer_Info];
-- ','');
```

This may well result in your `Customer_Info` table being dropped if the user that the code is connecting to SQL as has sufficient rights to do so.

Comment: @GragasIncoming, no, it's really not how you're doing it... you're concatenating the values into `query`, I'm passing them in as *parameters*. Those are fundamentally different ways of constructing the query that is passed to SQL Server. *Please* for the sake of anyone who's a customer of the company this code is written for, take half an hour to get a handle on why concatenation is bad. Here's a page from OWASP that has a few more examples that may help: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: i think it requires `connection.Open();` because it gives an error.

Answer (score 5):

Don't do it! Seriously, just don't. String interpolation is not suitable for building SQL. Just use parameters:

```
var query = @"
insert into Customer_info(Customer_Name,Customer_Phone)
values(@name,@phone);";
//...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("phone", phone);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Or use a library like dapper (which removes all the messy ADO.NET code for you, like commands, parameters, and readers):

```
conn.Execute(query, new { name, phone });
```

Comment: where are the try catch methods?

Comment: @GragasIncoming what am I catching and why? frankly, `using` is *far* more useful than `try`/`catch` - Rob's answer shows placement of that.

Comment: Then how would you output an error? E.g. inside catch function `ex.Message;`

Comment: @GragasIncoming if you mean re the `try`/`catch` in the question: they **weren't in the question** when I answered; also: your `catch` swallows the exception; also, it is pretty rare that you need to `Close()` a connection - it is far more often to use `using` for lifetime here. Note that re the dapper version: dapper will actually handle connection lifetime correctly *anyway* - if the connection isn't open when you call `Execute`, it'll open it, execute, and close it etc (it doesn't close it if it was open initially, obviously)

Comment: @GragasIncoming re "Then how would you output an error" - I'd probably catch that *much* closer to the code that is going to display the error; if your data access code and your UI code are intermixed, that's not great separation of concerns

Answer (score 4):

To use string interpolation you need to write:

```
var query = $"insert into Customer_info(Customer_Name,Customer_Phone) values('{name}','{phone}');";
```

But, of course you are prone to SQL Injection, which you should avoid!

Use `SqlCommand.Parameters` collection to add parameter and be safe from that thread.